# Cypress.io + TypeScript difference beetween: expect().to.equal() vs expect().equals() vs expect().to.eq()

Tags: typescript, assertions, browser-automation, cypress

What is the difference if we compare these 3 assertion methods:

```
expect().to.equal() vs expect().equals() vs expect().to.eq()
```

I found these assertions in Cypress.io documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the source](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/297c71a9924166ee38eef5fae85a587a813aed5d/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L1016-L1038), the effects of all of these are identical under the hood.

Comment: Hmm... so what is the point to have same assertion just with different names of it. They only duplicate each other then.

Comment: I’d guess that they felt it was more ergonomic—you can use whatever feels more natural on a case-to-case basis, just like you can choose between BDD and TDD, between `expect` and `should`—but that’s just speculation.

Comment: I can confirm, these three assertion methods have no functional difference.